# How do I retrive the value of a constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `NSLayoutConstraint` constraint:

```
var myConstantLeading: CGFloat = 10
var myConstantTrailing: CGFloat = 10

var myConstraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint (item: image,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: myConstantLeading)
    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraintLeading)

var myConstraintTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint (item: image,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: myConstantTrailing)
    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraintTrailing)
```

When an `UIButton` is pressed, the `image` gets scaled:

```
self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
```

Though, after the transformation finishes, the `constant` doesn't change:

```
println(myConstraint.constant) // equals to 10
println(myConstant) // equals to 10
```

I resized the image, hence the `constant`s should vary. Why isn't that happening?

Comment: Constraints don't change, they are static rules used to layout the views. Layout doesn't modify the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. May you please suggest a solution?

Comment: It's not really obvious what you are trying to do. Resizing a view that has a constant width (specified by left and right constraints) seems a bit fishy.

Comment: I need to get the value of the left and right constraints so that I can use them later on in another UIViewController to replicate the scaled image.

Comment: You know the image size, let's say it's `image.size.width`. You are multiplying the width by `0.8`, the left border of the view is at x equal to `10`. So the resulting position should be something like `10 + image.size.width * 0.8 / 2`. However instead of changing the transform, you could center the image in the superview, add a width constraint to it and then do `widthConstraint.constant *= 0.8`. Then you could just access `self.image.frame` to get the position of the image. Transform makes it just harder to get actual values.

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty good solution! Working on it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints you've set both use "Equal" relationships with a constant of 10pt from either side. If you change the image size without adjusting the constraints you've violated the constraint requirements & have an ambiguous layout.

If you want to observe the change in constant values they need to be allowed to change. You have to change "Equal" to "Greater Than Or Equal" so the constraint is allowed to vary from its current 10pt value. This of course assumes that the image can only shrink - it will never be larger than 10pt away from the edge, but it could be smaller.

You also still need to clearly define what you want to happen to the layout after transforming the image. If you want the image to remain centered after the button tap/resize, you would ideally just add a constraint to the image to center it horizontally in the container.

Adjusting only "=" to ">=" would still be ambiguous, because the system doesn't know how far from left or right the image should be, nor what the image width will be. You need to give it more information, such as "center horizontally in container" AND "leading & trailing edges >= 10pt from the superview".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You made a very good point. Please note I am creating not just one constraint, but two: the leading and the trailing constraint. I showed you just one to simplify things up. My bad, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Ok - please add that since it completes the picture of the desired outcome you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I appreciate your help! Working on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at UIView Class Reference [transform property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) you see a warning stating :

> If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

and since your view transform property is not the identity transform and its frame is undefined then all its constraints constants should be ignored as well because they are linked with view's frame

Comment: Thanks. So what's the solution? Could you please suggest other alternatives?

Comment: A possible solution for this would be scaling image by lowering constraint constant. Does it sounds good for you ?

Comment: That is a good idea but eventually I won't be able to retrive the values of the left and right constraints. I need to replicate the same image in another UIViewController, so I need to know what are the constants of the resized image.